# How to calculate percentage from a table on R

Tags: r, math, percentage

**[Hello,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCLj6.png)**

I have a table with 14 observations and 16 variables. (S0 to  S11 and the sum of the row at the end)
I would like to calculate the percentage of each value on the total (last column).
I tried prop.table but it's not giving me the right percentages. I also tried apply but same pb.

Here is a sample of my table :

```
Row.name    S0  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  Total
     S0     25987   269 9152    6042    30  32  41512
     S1     234 5575    768 4398    3321    34  14330
     S2     345546  35  79  245 21685   676 368266
     S3     5678    6   78  987 4657    789 12195
     S4     9   45  879 34  5768    246 6981
     S5     54  3   788 863 56  279826  281590
     S6     367 57678   12  842 436 5824    65159
```

The code I've tried :

```
prop.table(df)

prop <- apply(df, 1, function(x) x/ df$Total*100)
```

For the first line for example I would like to have
(25987/41512)*100    (269/41512)*100    (269/41512)*100 etc

Thank you for ur help.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`prop <- apply(df, 2,function(x,y) (x/y)*100,  df$Total)`

As you can read from `?apply`, the second argument is:

> a vector giving the subscripts which the function will be applied over. E.g., for a matrix
>   1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns

Therefore, you should use 2 instead of 1, for you want to compute percentage across columns.
Also, your lambda function requires an extra argument: it is the field Total for each row. 
Again, as you can read from `?apply` all those optional arguments for the function should go at the very end of apply.

Finally, just clarify that you would also create a final column which is always 1, because percentage of the last column (Total) it is also to be computed using apply.

Best!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @DebanjanB

Answer (score 2):

`prop.table()` gives the proportion of total as default but has a margin argument to calculate row or column percentages. I think `prop.table(df[,2:7], margin = 1) * 100` should work. Where the 1 indicates that row proportions are to be calculated (2 indicates column proportions). The `2:7` index excludes the `Total` column and the `Row.name` column as these are not necessary for the function.

Edit: Depending on the class of `df` it may be necessary to convert it to a matrix first. `prop.table(as.matrix(df[,2:7]), margin = 1) * 100` should work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) functions 
[gather](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html), 
[mutate](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html), 
[select](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html) 
and [spread](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread.html) for this purpose.

Load packages and data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
sampletable <- "Row.name    S0  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  Total
S0     25987   269 9152    6042    30  32  41512
S1     234 5575    768 4398    3321    34  14330
S2     345546  35  79  245 21685   676 368266
S3     5678    6   78  987 4657    789 12195
S4     9   45  879 34  5768    246 6981
S5     54  3   788 863 56  279826  281590
S6     367 57678   12  842 436 5824    65159 "
dtf <- read.table(text= sampletable, header = TRUE)
# I prefer lowercase names
names(dtf) <- tolower(names(dtf))
```

Transform the data in long format, one observation per row

```
dtflong <- dtf %>% 
    gather(col.name, value, -row.name, -total) %>% 
    mutate(percent = round(value / total *100, 2))
head(dtflong)
  row.name  total col.name  value percent
1       S0  41512       s0  25987   62.60
2       S1  14330       s0    234    1.63
3       S2 368266       s0 345546   93.83
4       S3  12195       s0   5678   46.56
5       S4   6981       s0      9    0.13
6       S5 281590       s0     54    0.02
```

Reshape in wide format

```
dtflong %>% 
    select(-total, -value) %>% 
    spread(col.name, percent)

  row.name    s0    s1    s2    s3    s4    s5
1       S0 62.60  0.65 22.05 14.55  0.07  0.08
2       S1  1.63 38.90  5.36 30.69 23.18  0.24
3       S2 93.83  0.01  0.02  0.07  5.89  0.18
4       S3 46.56  0.05  0.64  8.09 38.19  6.47
5       S4  0.13  0.64 12.59  0.49 82.62  3.52
6       S5  0.02  0.00  0.28  0.31  0.02 99.37
7       S6  0.56 88.52  0.02  1.29  0.67  8.94
```

Optionally, check if the total column is correct

```
dtflong %>% 
    group_by(row.name, total) %>% 
    summarise(total2 = sum(value)) %>% 
    mutate(diff = total2 - total)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   row.name [7]
  row.name  total total2  diff
  <fct>     <int>  <int> <int>
1 S0        41512  41512     0
2 S1        14330  14330     0
3 S2       368266 368266     0
4 S3        12195  12195     0
5 S4         6981   6981     0
6 S5       281590 281590     0
7 S6        65159  65159     0
```